# How to compute the intersection between two hyper-rectangles?

Tags: geometry

A hyper-rectangle is the generalization of a rectangle for higher dimensions(n>2). It contains points or vectors of n dimensions. It is defined by two vectors of n dimensions: Hmax and Hmin. Hmax and Hmin are respectively the maximum and the minimum of each dimension of the all points contained in the hyper-rectangle.

Given two hyper-rectangles R1 and R2, how to compute the intersection between R1 and R2?

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried?

Comment: @Ernie060     Given the method d(x,R)=euclidean_distance( 0, maximum(0,maximum(R.Hmin-x,x-R.Hmax) ) ) the minimum euclidean distance between the hyper-rectangle R and the n dimensions vector.  I tried to check if R1 is in R2 and inversely. To check if R1 is in R2 I see if d(R1.mins,R2) = 0 and d(R1.maxes,R2) = 0. Similary to check if R2 is in R1 I see d(R2.mins,R1) = 0 and d(R2.maxes,R1) = 0. But I don't know how to compute the intersection between R1 and R2 if neither of the two hyper-rectangles is completely included in the other.